# Custom Style on React-Bootstrap's Dropdown Menu component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I am trying to apply a custom css style to a react bootstrap component, but cannot figure how to access elements that are not explicit in the component's JSX. For example:

```
<ButtonGroup>
      <DropdownButton className="ddown" id="ddown" title="Dropdown">
      <MenuItem className="itemxx" href="#books">Books</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem className="itemxx" href="#podcasts">Podcasts</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem className="itemxx" href="#">Tech I Like</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem className="itemxx" href="#">About me</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem className="itemxx" href="#addBlog">Add a Blog</MenuItem>
      </DropdownButton>
    </ButtonGroup>
```

has no outlet for the Dropdown box, which I am looking to give a specific width and eliminate its rounded corners. Is there a way that I can access it in my css?

EDIT:

Here is the element I want to edit, which by the way if I try to access through .dropdown-menu, 1) I change all dropdowns, and 2) I cant change most of its values.

[image]

Comment: In your `index.js` just define the stylesheet and make changes to the classes you define in the `className` section. Can you verify what's not working?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment below, the problem is that I want to make changes to the dropdown menu (or box), but if you see the code, I only have tags for the button, and the menu items (not the same as the actual menu), so I have no tag for the actual Menu to define.

Answer (score 5):

Add a custom className to `<MenuItem></MenuItem>` and edit it by appending a `a` at the end of className in your .css file while customising.

In your .js file:

`<MenuItem className="dropdown-link"> DaItem </MenuItem>`

In your .css file: (Note the `a` in the selector)

`.dropdown-link a {background: red; color: yellow;}`

P.S: You may need to add `!important` in .css

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, I found an way to this! I was able to access the specific menu by including [aria-labelledby = ddown] (ddown is my dropdown's custom class) on the CSS like so:

```
.dropdown-menu[aria-labelledby = ddown] {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-width: 80px; //This, by the way, is not working for some reason.
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just add an extra class with `className="ddown ddown-custom"`?

Comment: Thanks Dandy. Because the tag I am trying to access is "written" by bootstrap, but nowhere in my code do I get access to name the actual tag that I need which is the Dropdown Menu (not the dropdown button you see in my code above).

Answer (score 0):

you use DropDown.Menu and DropDown.Item in the following way

```
<Dropdown.Menu className="my-dropdown">
  <Dropdown.Divider />
  <Dropdown.Item className="itemxx" href="#books">Books</Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item>className="itemxx" href="#podcasts">Podcasts</Dropdown.Item>
</Dropdown.Menu>
```

and then add your customs CSS like

```
.my-dropdown {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```