# how to show options on hover in react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I have added DropDownButton in  my react code I want to show all options on hover to my button but I searched in docs I dint get any options for this below is my code

```
<DropdownButton
                                bsSize="small"
                                className="ddown"
                                role="menuitem"
                                title="Prgoram Profile">
                                <MenuItem href="#books">Books</MenuItem>

                            </DropdownButton>
```

can anyone please let me know how to do it? I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274950/custom-style-on-react-bootstraps-dropdown-menu-component) but Idint get much idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im unsure about react bootstrap in general though you could use vanilla react by make use of the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events

e.g.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            show: false
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <DropdownButton
            bsSize="small"
            className="ddown"
            role="menuitem"
            title="Program Profile"
            onMouseEnter={(e) => this.setState({ show: true })}
            onMouseLeave={(e) => this.setState({ show: false })}
            open={this.state.show}>
            <MenuItem href="#books">Books</MenuItem>

            </DropdownButton>
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: ive been looking through the react bootstrap documentation, the error you got above is because you must initialize the state in the constructor.

Comment: see the above edits. after reviewing the context of the react-bootstrap module, I think the above should work

Comment: I tried unfortunately it is not able to understand this events.:(

Comment: ^ check the above documentation and see if this helps

Comment: awesome, I'd appreciate an accept and an upvote if you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

this solution works great but if you have more than one DropdownButton in your component it will open all menus at once when you hover on one of them...

so based on [canaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7496355/canaan-seaton) solution and according to my scenario i made something like this:

```
createNavDropDownItem(item, index, id) {

        const tabsArray = item.Children.filter(item => !item.notATab);
        const items = tabsArray.map((item, index) => (<MenuItem {...this.getSharedProps(item, index)}>
            <a>{SDK.RequestBuilderUtils.getFormatMessage(this.language, this.messages, item.Name, item.Name)}</a>
        </MenuItem>));
        return <NavDropdown
            {...this.getSharedProps(item, index)}
            onMouseEnter={(e) => this.setState({ [`show-${index}`]: true })}
            onMouseLeave={(e) => this.setState({ [`show-${index}`]: false })}
            open={this.state[`show-${index}`]}
        >
            {items}
        </NavDropdown>

    }
```